# Delphi 2007, not all installed printers show in printer setup dialog

Tags: delphi, printers

I have two users now that tell me that the standard TPrinterSetupDialog in our Delphi 2007 application does not list all installed printers.

One user just installed a Canon D1300, it is selected as the default printer in control panel but does not even show in the list in the PrinterSetupDialog.

Another user reported the same problem with a Xerox Phaser 8560, it was also the default printer in control panel.

Is there any know reason that this could happen.

John Taylor

Comment: What operating system? Network or local printers? Are they installed before your app starts, or while it's running?

Comment: customer running Windows XP, the printer is a network printer.  The printer is installed on the system, my app has nothing to do with installing it, it is just not listed as available printer in TprintDialog where I give the user a choice of what printer to print to. John Taylor

Comment: I just got some further information from user, as it turns out the printer is connected to their router , not to any network computer, I hope that sheds more light on the possible solution.

Comment: Now, they say the problem has disappeared, they rebooted the computer.  Apparently, they installed the printer, did not reboot and did not restart our software.  Thanks Ken for your response.